# How should I understand the word "повем" in the line "кому повем печаль мою"?

Tags: значения, word

This is a quotation from Chekhov's story "Тоска"(See https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B2)#cite_note-1). I have googled but couldn't find anything about the meaning of the word "повем".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the first line of a spiritual chant called [*Стих плача Иосифа Прекраснаго, егда продаша братия его во Египет*](http://feb-web.ru/feb/byliny/texts/bst/bst-7272.htm?cmd=p) ("A verse of lamentation of Joseph the Most Beautiful when his brethren sold him into Egypt").

It means "to whom shall I tell of my sorrow".

*Повем* here is a rendition of the Church Slavonic form *повѣмь* ("I will tell", literally "I will let know").

It's one of a small bunch of so called athematic verbs, whose conjugation endings lacked vowels and attached directly to stems. There were more verbs like that in Proto-Indo-European but only a few of them remained in Proto-Slavic.

There were five such verbs in Church Slavonic: *быти* "to be", *дати* "to give", *вѣдѣти* "to know", *ѣсти* "to eat", *имѣти* "to have".

Two of those verbs retained the athematic endings in modern Russian: *я ем*, *я дам*, others have lost it: *поведаю* is the modern Russian way of saying *повѣмь*.

A couple of athematic forms are fossilized in set phrases like *бог весть* ("God (only) knows"), *власть имущие* ("the powers that be", literally "those who have power") etc.

Answer (score 2):

It is not quite Russian, it is Old Slavonic.

A more understandable for Russian version will be **поведаю**, and the most Russian is ***расскажу***.

"Whom can I tell about my sorrow?"

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I also want to know where I can find references on Old Slavonic.

Comment: You can read about старославянский язык and церковно-славянский язык online.